# The problem with the entry in the cookie from a query to mysql database

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I have a problem with writing to a cookie data from a query to a mysql database.The response from the query to the database comes and is written to cookies, but it writes data to them with the type **urlencoded** and  the cookie displays as "**userName=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2"**, because I use bodyParser.urlencodedParser to retrieve data from a form from a site. 
Here's the code:

```
app.post("/singIn", urlencodedParser, function (request, response) {
    if(!request.body) return response.sendStatus(400);
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users where (${(request.body.login.includes('@') === true) ? 
                                                 `email='${request.body.login}'` : 
                                                 `telephone=${request.body.login}`}) 
                                                  and password=${request.body.password}`,
                    (err, results) => {
        if(err == null && results !=[]) {
            response.cookie('userName', `${results[0].user_name}`);// this have urlencoded
            response.sendFile(`${__dirname}/public/index.html`);
        } else if(err != null)  
            throw new Error(err);
        connection.end();    
    });
});
```

I have tried different ways already, but none of what I found on the Internet helped me. I will be grateful for any help or tips where to look next

Comment: What is your error or problem? Do you need to use the login and password from your html form to build a sql ? or How write a cookie from sql result?

Comment: I need write a cookie from sql result, but data have urlencoded coded

Comment: **data** is the result of sql or the values from your html form?

Comment: Data is Result of sql

Comment: what is the value of **results[0].user_name**? is this value in your database?

Comment: Yes, this is user name

Comment: Why do you say, that this value is encoded?

Comment: I need value type string, but this value urlencoded type